# What is the meaning of "if (this[x])" in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript game engine called panda, and I'm getting an error in the console ("Uncaught Class BG already created"). And when I explore the source code of the engine, I found the code that is throwing the error (below).

In the second `if` statement what is the meaning of `this[name]`? I don't understand what exactly it's saying.

```
createClass: function(name, extend, content) {
    if (typeof name === 'object') return this.Class.extend(name);

    if (this[name]) throw 'Class ' + name + ' already created';

    if (typeof extend === 'object') {
        content = extend;
        extend = 'Class';
    }
```

Comment: It checks if the `this` object has an attribute with the name of `name` (whatever the variable holds) which is *truthy*. `this['foo']` is the same as `this.foo`, only that `'foo'` can be a variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two type of notation in JavaScript to refer object properties.

```
var Employee = { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Smith" }
```

**1. Dot notation**

```
Employee.firstname; // John
Employee.lastname; // Smith
```

**2. Bracket notation**

```
var fname = "firstname";
var lname = "lastname";

Employee[fname]; // John
Employee[lname]; // Smith
```

So, incase if the object property is a variable we can user bracket notation.

So in your case `this[name]` is referring to a property on this object.

Comment: What is called "*subscript/array notation*" here is called "bracket notation" in the language specification (and just about everywhere else), see [*ECMA-262 §12.3.2*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors).

Answer (score 0):

This is not really clear from the fragment of code, you've posted, but this might be some kind of class container.

`if(this[name]) ...` Checks for existence of property with the given name (which in this context shows if the class with such name is already registered.)

The fact you are getting the error means that you have tried to register two classes with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

`this[X]` will check inside `if condition` value is `undefined`

```
if (this[name]) throw 'Class ' + name + ' already created';
```

if `this[name]` is `undefined` will not goes into `if` statement.

**Example**

```
var chkCondition;

alert(chkCondition);

// This will not goes inside if because chkCondition is undefined.
if (chkCondition) {
  alert('yes');
}

chkCondition="A";

// Now chkCondition has value "A" that's why it will return 
// true and goes inside if and alert "yes"
if (chkCondition) {
  alert('yes');
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/83w339Lz/)